# Retrieving data to dropdown menu from database but it is not displaying there

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get values from database to drop-down list using jQuery. But nothing is showing in the dropdown list.

Here is the code:

getlist.php

```
<?php   
 
 $conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project"); 
  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM catd";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    
$scat_arr = array();
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
 {
    $catid = $row['cid'];
    $catname = $row['catname'];
    $scat_arr[] = array("cid" => $catid, "catname" => $catname);
}
echo json_encode($scat_arr);
 ?>
```

catdet.php

This is where I want to retrieve the value:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center">
Subategory Name : <input type="text" name="scname"><br><br>
Category Name : <select id="catn"> </select><br><br>
Subategory description : <input type="text" name="scdes"><br><br>
<input type="file" name="scimg" id="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("getlist.php", function(return_data){
  $.each(return_data.data, function(key,value){
    $("#catn").append("<option value=" + value.cid +">"+value.catname+"</option>");
  });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: What does your console show? where is `data` coming from?

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Does the backend return the data in proper format? Does it return any data? Is there anything written to your browser's console?

Comment: it showing  nothing... but data is retrived from database corrctly ..i checked that

Comment: but select field is still empty

Comment: `$.each(return_data.data,`  where does the `.data` coming from?

Comment: from getlist.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this script i have just changed the foreach part

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("getlist.php", function(return_data){
            // <edited part>
            return_data.forEach(function(e,i){
                $('#catn').append('<option value= "'+e.cid+'">'+e.catname+'</option>');
            });
            // </edited part>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think the problem was on the quotation part. here, $("#catn").append("<option value=" + value.cid +">"+value.catname+"</option>");

Comment: Oomggggg its workingg thank youuuuu.... you are a lifesaver..thanksssssss